# Searching for consecutive numbers in a group

Tags: vb.net

I'm making a Poker game for myself and I have the rest of the code but I can't seem to find out how to search seven cards to see if there is a straight(5 field cards and 2 cards in the player's hand), the cards are numbers (1 being ace, 2 being 2, etc.. 11 being jack, 12 being queen etc.) I have this so far:

```
Function isStraight(ByVal Player As String)
    Dim h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 As String
    h1 = 0
    h2 = 1
    h3 = 2
    h4 = 3
    h5 = 4
    Dim z1, z2 As String
    If Player = "P1" Then
        z1 = P1Card1
        z2 = P1Card2
    ElseIf Player = "P2" Then
        z1 = P2Card1
        z2 = P2Card2
    End If 
    Dim cntr As Integer = 0
    Do
        cntr = cntr + 1
        h1 = h1 + 1
        h2 = h2 + 1
        h3 = h3 + 1
        h4 = h4 + 1
        h5 = h5 + 1
        If A(FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4, FC5) Or A(FC5, FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4) Or A(FC4, FC5, FC1, FC2, FC3) Or A(FC3, FC4, FC5, FC1, FC2) Then

        End If
    Loop
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your code would probably benefit from turning Option Strict On.  You are defining several string variables (h1 - h5) and then storing integers in them and later performing mathematical operations on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using numeric values for the cards, you should use Integer rather than String for the data type. Think about designing your methods to work this way:

```vb
'Accept only cards, use a specific Boolean return type
'IEnumerable(Of Integer) will still allow you to pass arrays to this function
Function isStraight(ByVal River As IEnumerable(Of Integer), ByVal Hand As IEnumerable(Of Integer)) As Boolean

    'Make sure Option Infer is On
    Dim Cards = River.Concat(Hand)

    'Ace can be high or low, so add a high value to the list if you have any aces
    If Cards.Contains(1) Then Cards = Cards.Concat(New Integer() {14}) 

    'It will be MUCH easier to find consecutive cards if they are sorted in order to start with, and we don't care about pairs so limit us to unique number cards
    'The "Function(c) c" here is called a Lambda Expression. This lambda expression tells the OrderBy() method to compare items in the collection for sorting purposes using simple ascending order. 
    Cards = Cards.OrderBy(Function(c) c ).Distinct()

    'If this count gets to five consecutive cards, we have a straight
    Dim StraightCount As Integer 

    'Initialize to a card that can never be consecutive, so first time through the loop will reset the counter
    Dim PreviousCard Integer = -1 

    For Each card As Integer In Cards
       'If the prior card is one less than current card, they are consecutive: add 1 to StraightCount
       'If they are not consecutive, set back to 1 (this is the 1st card in a new potential straight)
       StraightCount = If(card - PreviousCard = 1, StraightCount + 1, 1)

       'If we reach 5, don't bother finishing: Return True immediately
       If StraightCount = 5 Then Return True

       'Set this card as the prior card for the next loop iteration
       PreviousCard = card
    Next card

    'Did not find a straight
    Return False
End Function
```